# Algorithm to Compare Ranges

Tags: mysql, algorithm

A user is inputting a range of acceptable values, say 30 - 60.

He wants to know which entries in a database have at least one value in that inputted range. So if input is 30 - 60, and there is an entry of 59 - 100, then that is a match. Also a match would be 20 - 80, 40 - 50 or 28 - 32. Because all of them have at least one value that matches the inputted range.

However, with an input range of 30 - 60, an entry of 10 - 20 or 70 - 100 should be rejected.

The ranges are held in a MySQL database with two fields - min and max.

Any idea how to query / compare this?

Comment: it's simple logic.....

Comment: Consider two ranges: Xa-Xb and Ya-Yb. You want values where Xa < Yb AND Xb > Ya

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `BETWEEN` operator like

```
select * from table1 where values between 30 and 60;
```

(OR) `where values between 59 and 100;`

You can as well use `>` and `<` operator to get the same evaluation

```
select * from table1 where values >= 30 and values <= 60;
```

If it's a range comparison as Strawberry pointed in comment then you can check like

```
where 30 < 59 and 59 < 60 and 60 < 100;
```

Comment: That's comparing a value with a range. The OP wants to compare a range with a range

Comment: @Strawberry, thanks for pointing that ... looks my understanding went wrong. let me check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check 3 posibilities in your WHERE sentence:

1) When table minvalue is between value1 and value2
2) When table maxvalue is between value1 and value2
3) When table minvalue is lower than value1 and maxvalue is greater than value2

For instance:

**Build the database**

```
create table demo (
id int,
beginning int,
ending int);
insert into demo(id,beginning,ending)
values (1,30,60);


insert into demo(id,beginning,ending)
values (2,0,60);

insert into demo(id,beginning,ending)
values (3,50,60);

insert into demo(id,beginning,ending)
values (4,60,100);

insert into demo(id,beginning,ending)
values (5,60,61);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM demo 
WHERE beginning BETWEEN 50 AND 55
OR ending BETWEEN 50 AND 55
OR (beginning < 50 AND ending > 55)
```

**Returns**

ID  BEGINNING   ENDING

1   30  60

2   0   60

3   50  60

Regards,